# I recently installed java jdk1.6.0_23 java programname wont work for me?

Tags: java

javac is working ok and producing the .class file but when I try to use the java command I get the following error msg

Error opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.

I added the setting for the classpath to the bin of the java installation

What have I done wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `I added the setting for the classpath to the bin of the java installation` what exactly you did here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some keys in registry holding some erronous [deleted] entries.

Best way is to uninstall current version and install fresh one.